# $E,F$ disjoint subsets of $D$ having no limit point in $D$ ; to show a meromorphic function with poles exactly in $E$ and zeros exactly in $F$

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions, weierstrass-factorization

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb C$ be an open set and $E,F$ be disjoint subsets of $D$ having no limit point in $D$ . Then how to show that there there is a meromorphic function in $D$ such that $f$ has a simple pole at every point of $E$ , has a simple zero at every point of $F$ and $f$ has no other poles or zeros ?

I think I have to use both Weierstrass factorization and Mittag-Lefler ; but I am unable to see how to do it . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: For any sequence $b_n$ without converging subquence, there is a sequence $a_n > 0$ such that $f(z) = \sum_n \frac{a_n}{z-b_n}$ converges absolutely on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{b_n\}$, which means it is meromorphic with poles only at $b_n$. For the zeros, the idea is the same with products https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Existence_of_entire_function_with_specified_zeroes

Comment: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} |b_n| = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} |c_n| = \infty$ then let $E_k(z) =  \log(1-z) + \sum_{m=1}^k \frac{z^m}{m} = \mathcal{O}(z^{k+1})$ and $$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty E_n(z/b_n)-E_n(z/c_n), \qquad F(z) = e^{f(z)}$$ Is it analytic/meromorphic ? What are its zeros and poles ?

Comment: @user1952009 : what are you trying to say ? what are those $b_n  , c_n$ etc. ?